# Avoid session hijacking in site with http

Tags: session, cookies, web, https, session-hijacking

as I know the only way to avoid session hijacking in `https` ,but some times we don't want to use it. so I think about alternative way for it.

I explain my way,can it be possible or is it good way?

think we have third part server ( I called it Padra ) ,which give you API to check session and cookies,you will call Padra jt file in your web site views ( session and cookies saved by Padra domain name and you don't have direct access to it,but padra use SSL),then you can check the session and cookies value in server side by calling Padra API.

what do you think about it?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work to not just https.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a particularly good trade-off.

Issues:

- You've decreased the confidence users have in your site (even if you
  have a secure implementation, it wont have the padlock/green bar/etc)
- Your users now have an additional asset to download, parse, run and
  so slows their experience
- If third-party cookies are [disabled](http://blog.mozilla.org/privacy/2013/02/25/firefox-getting-smarter-about-third-party-cookies/) it doesn't work at all
- You've added additional complexity throughout, and now also have an
  additional external dependency on your backend you have to manage

Answer (score 0):

HTTP-ONLY header helps prevent common session hijacking and XSS vulnerabilities . Instead of going through so much trouble u can try using this .